# Tracking Scrolling Virtual Page Views in GA

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

Update: Looking into making sure script does not cache events, search has not gone well at all so far.

I am using the script below to track virtual page views in GA, the site has a very long homepage we are tracking this on. The problem I am having is that once the user scrolls down to a lower section, it does not register as a new page view if they scroll back up (making it a maximum of 1 view per page). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. I am using jQuery and the script below does send/track.

This script is in addition to the Universal Analytics code being implemented just before the  tag. The first code below is the normal Analytics code, which is needed to run the debugger properly because that is where the account is define. The second script is the one that I am having the issue with.

Normal UA script (located in the head tags):

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-123456-1', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

Script for scrolling virtual page views:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

// Predefined variable 
Frequency = 10;    

//Tracking and Sending
_frequency = Frequency; 
_repetition = 100 / Frequency; 
var _scrollMatrix = new Array(); 
for (ix = 0; ix < _repetition; ix++) {
    _scrollMatrix[ix] = [_frequency, 'false'];
    _frequency = Frequency + _frequency; 
} 
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    for (iz = 0; iz < _scrollMatrix.length; iz++) {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >=      $(document).height() 
* _scrollMatrix[iz][0] / 100)  && (_scrollMatrix[iz][1]== 'false')) {
            _scrollMatrix[iz][1] = 'true';
            ga('send', 'pageview', _scrollMatrix[iz][0]+'%' );
        }
    }
 });

</script>
```

[image: This is how it currently shows in Analytics]

Comment: I have been advised that all I need to do is modify the code not to cache the scroll points, or to reset the cache on each scroll event. I will be looking into how to do this.

Comment: You need to do more than that. At least you would need to remove the loop from the scroll event because you are sending the values from 10%-100% on every scroll, and you would need to fix the call to Google Analytics to the correct method call (and to send the actual position of the user in the page).  I really did not write my answer below to annoy you or something but to point several problems with your script.

Comment: I don't mean to make it seem as though I am ignoring your suggestion, I really do appreciate the time & effort you have put into this. But, from every test I have done with this, it does report to Google Analytics as intended, with the exception of once a user scrolls down to the XX% and that page view sends, it does not send again if the user returns to that scroll position. 



Using the format of ga('send', 'pageview', 'page path'); does properly send to GA, as that is what they suggest for a basic virtual page view.
I am by no means a coding expert but they are sending (once) as intended.

Comment: I added an image of the 'page views' I am currently getting on the site. I will rename these through a filter if we are able to get it to send again when a user scrolls back up the page. (I did only show the first 10 rows, which is why the 100% does not show up)

Comment: I just realized that I did not accurately explain that this script is in addition to the normal Universal Analytics script. In order for it to work in the debugger you must have the normal script above it, declaring the account. I will edit the question to show that in the script. My apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Yup, you are right of course - third parameter might hold a virtual pagename. Still that doesn't address the other problems I mentioned below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You script creates an array of arrays with threshold values ranging from 10 to 100 as index, as determined by the "repentance" variable (this does not mean what you think it means; you mean "repetitions", unless you are really sorry for writing this script). One of the values for each element if your array of the array is a boolean "false".

This boolean value is evaluated in the loop inside the document.scroll function. If the value is "false" the pageview is executed, and the variable is set to "true". Happens in this bit:

```
if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >=      $(document).height() 
* _scrollMatrix[iz][0] / 100)  && (_scrollMatrix[iz][1]== 'false')) {
            _scrollMatrix[iz][1] = 'true';
```

That means the next time around the boolean for `_scrollMatrix[iz][1]` is "true" and the if branch is no longer executed.

If you want to fire the Google Analytics code regardless you can remove the boolean value and the part where it's evaluated. So your script would look like this:

```
<script language="javascript"> 

// Predefined variable 
Frequency = 10;    

//Tracking and Sending
_frequency = Frequency; 
_repentance = 100 / Frequency; 
var _scrollMatrix = new Array(); 
for (ix = 0; ix < _repentance; ix++) {
    _scrollMatrix[ix] = [_frequency];
    _frequency = Frequency + _frequency; 
} 
$(document).scroll(function (e) {
    for (iz = 0; iz < _scrollMatrix.length; iz++) {
        if (($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >=      $(document).height() * _scrollMatrix[iz][0] / 100)  ) {
            ga('send', 'pageview', _scrollMatrix[iz][0]+'%' );
        }
    }
 });

</script>
```

While you say that the script is tracking I have to point out that the resulting GA code is actually wrong. Your tracking calls look like this:

```
ga("send", "pageview", "10%")
ga("send", "pageview", "20%")
...
```

You cannot simply put in the naked percentage as an argument to that function and hope that it gets recorded somewhere (**Edit** oops, my bad. Of course the third parameter works as virtual pagename, so that bit is alright if you want the percentage as pagename).

Since your script executes the loop on every scroll event it actually sends dozens of ga calls, and the computed percentages do not relate to the actual scroll position of the user (it simply sends all values from 10-100% for each scroll event). Plus looping on every scroll event makes this horribly expensive in terms of browser ressources. And of course you have a quota of hits per second and hits per sessions, and your script will hit those quotas pretty quickly.

I would frankly recommend that you abandon your script and use one of the existing tested solutions. The [jQuery scrollDepth](http://scrolldepth.parsnip.io/) plugin is quite nice and you should be able to adapt it to your needs (more easily than rewriting your own).

Comment: Is it possible to send the custom event like `ga("send", "pageScroll", true)` ?

Comment: No. Hit types are prefined - pageView, event, usertiming and a few others. There is no scroll event hit type in analytics. You can send an event, which requires a few parameters (category and action, and optionally  label and value - see here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events).

Comment: I will look into the scrollDepth plugin you suggested. And the "repetitions" issue is something that I am not entirely sure how I overlooked it.

However, the tracking calls in the format below does appear fine in Analytics and allow for adjustments of names through simple filters. (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/upgrade/reference/gajs-analyticsjs#virtual-pageviews)

ga("send", "pageview", "10%")

The real issue was that the page views only fired once and did not repeat if a user scrolled back up the page.

Comment: After reading your comments about the boolean vale again, I believe I understand what you are saying (I think). I have tried to remove that and tested it through the real-time view and it shows that is the issue. However as you indirectly mentioned, removing that showed how many hits it really is trying to send. (if I scroll down once to the 10% section, it sends roughly 30 page views). I will now look into limiting the number of hits per second (if possible) and see if I can make the script only send a maximum of X page views/second.